# PHP does not redirect to a page after login

Tags: php, html, database, session, redirect

I have a problem i have been trying to get my head around for a few days now. I have a website with many pages but the problem I have is that I am trying to run a session that when a user logs in, the navigation bar will change to something like "Hi user" with the option to log out or look at pages that are only accessible when the user is logged on. 
Any help is greatly appreciated as i am completely hopeless about this right now as I really do not know where the error is.

Page 1: login.php - this is where the user will log in.

```
<?php
include ('logon.php');
?>
<html>
<body>
    <?php
        include('navbar.php');
    ?>
    <form action="login.php" method="post" name="login" id="login">
                    Username:
                        <br>
                    <input type="text" name="Username" required>
                        <br><br>
                    Password:
                        <br>
                    <input type="password" name="Password" id="password" required>
                        <br><br>
                <input name="login" type="Submit" value="Login" id="Login">
            </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Page 2: logon.php - this is the page that fetches information from the database and runs the session.

```
    $Username = $_POST['Username']; 
    $Password = $_POST['Password'];

    $S_Username = $_POST['S_Username']; 
    $Pass = $_POST['Password'];

    $Management_Username = $_POST['Management_Username']; 
    $Passwd = $_POST['Password'];

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM Clients WHERE Username='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $Username) . "' && Password='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $Password). "'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$queryadmin = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM S_Organiser WHERE S_Username='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $S_Username) . "' && Password='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $Pass). "'";
$resultadmin = mysqli_query($connection, $queryadmin);
$rowadmin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultadmin);

$querymanagement = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM Management WHERE Username='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $Management_Username) . "' && Password='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $Passwd). "'";
$resultmanagement = mysqli_query($connection, $querymanagement);
$rowmanagement = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultmanagement);

if ($row["cnt"] > 0) 
{
    $_SESSION["userlogged"] =  $Username;
    header("Location: sorganiser.php");
    die();
} 
else if ($rowadmin["cnt"] > 0 )
    {
        $_SESSION["adminlogged"] = $S_Username;
        header("Location: logon.php");
    }
else if ($rowmanagement["cnt"] > 0 )
    {
        $_SESSION["managementlogged"] = $Management_Username;
        header("Location: logon.php");
    }
else 
{
    echo 'Not a valid login, please check your username and password!';
}
}
?>
```

Page 3: navbar.php - this is the navigation bar page that should change once the session has started

```
if(isset($_SESSION['userlogged']))
{
    echo '<div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li><li>
                <a href="register.php">Register</a></li><li>
                <a href="login.php">Log In</a></li><li>
                <a href="admin.php">Admin</a></li><li>
                <a href="">|</li>
                <li class="Username"> Hi '.$_SESSION['userlogged'].'</li>      
                    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>';
}

else if(isset($_SESSION['adminlogged']))
{
    echo '<div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li><li>
                <a href="register.php">Register</a></li><li>
                <a href="login.php">Log In</a></li><li>
                <a href="admin.php">Admin</a></li> 
                <a href="">|</li>
                <li class="S_Username"> Hi '.$_SESSION['adminlogged'].'</li>      
                    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                    <li><a href="add.php">Products</a></li>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>';
}
else if(isset($_SESSION['managementlogged']))
{
    echo '<div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li><li>
                <a href="register.php">Register</a></li><li>
                <a href="login.php">Log In</a></li><li>
                <a href="admin.php">Admin</a></li> 
                <a href="">|</li>
                <li class="Management_Username"> Hi '.$_SESSION['managementlogged'].'</li>      
                    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>';
}
else
{
echo '<div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li><li>
                <a href="register.php">Register</a></li><li>
                <a href="login.php">Log In</a></li><li>
                <a href="admin.php">Admin</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </div>';
}
?>
```

Page 4: client.php - this is the page that the user will be able to see once they login.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['userlogged'])) 
{
header('Location: logon.php?redirect=client.php');
exit;
}
include ('logon.php');
?>
<html>
<body>
    <?php
        include('navbar.php');
    ?>
    <?if(!isset($_SESSION['userlogged'])) 
      {
      echo "Welcome" .$_SESSION['userlogged'].", this is your login page!";
      }
      else
      echo "You must be logged in to view this page."?>
</body>
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: Can you debug your app so you can shorten your code demonstration to the necessary part only?

Comment: Btw, this line `<?if(!isset($_SESSION['userlogged']))` make sure you've got short tags enabled. Otherwise, do `<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['userlogged']))` and add `exit;` after each header.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'm quite new to php so I'm not sure what you mean by short tags enabled, could you explain? Sorry to bother you, i truly am a novice at this.

Comment: Just see if `<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['userlogged']))` works as opposed to `<?if(!isset($_SESSION['userlogged']))` and enable error reporting and db error checking as I said.

Comment: You also don't have a name attribute for S_Username in your form in regards to `$_POST['S_Username']` which your query is dependant upon. Error reporting would have thrown an undefined index for it. Nor for Management_Username for `$Management_Username = $_POST['Management_Username'];`. So, what I've given you to debug your code is ample enough for you to figure out where you've gone wrong.

Comment: I have enabled error reporting and done what you said it now gives me:  Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /home/bf13/13421254/public_html/CSY2028/a1/navbar.php on line 3

Comment: You only redirect to client.php inside client.php. But how do you get there in the first place?

Comment: This client.php page is supposed to be hidden only when you log in the login.php will the redirect the user to that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First start the session in login.php:

```
 <?php
    // Start the session
    session_start();
 ?>
```

Then define your input values :

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$username = $password = "";
?>
```

Then your form comes with action to itself :

```
<html>
    <body>

        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" name="login" id="login">
                        Username:
                            <br>
                        <input type="text" name="Username" value="<?php echo $username;?>" required>
                            <br><br>
                        Password:
                            <br>
                        <input type="password" name="Password" id="password" value="<?php echo $password;?>"   required>
                        <br><br>
                <input name="login" type="Submit" value="Login" id="Login">
            </form>
</body>
</html>
```

After that make your user control here like this :

The same control that you do in logon.php whether the user exists in the database:

```
if($row["cnt"] > 0)
{
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
    $_SESSION["username"] = $name;
    $_SESSION["password"]    = $password;
    header( "Location: sorganiser.php" );
}
else if($row["cnt"] == 0 and $username!="" and $password!=""){

    header( "Location: fail.php" );
}
```

And in the sorganizer.php just start session at the top of the page so that you can use the information of that user like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

?>

<?php

$username = $_SESSION["username"];
$password = $_SESSION["password"];

?>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for all your help although something has come up. I now have a session_start(); on logon.php and navbar.php only but it still comes up with the error of: Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() on navbar.php... any idea what could be causing this?
Thank you once again you have been a tremendous help.

Comment: Hi, have you tried to  if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); } on the top of the navbar.php ?

Answer (score 0):

give this a go: and you need a session at the top of every page that will use sessions. I dont see one on the top page.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])){

    //if there's no session present, display this.                  
    echo "<a href='#' class=' btn btn-primary'>Login</a>";

}else{ 

    //else theres a session so diplay this.                               
    echo "<a href='#' class='btn btn-warning'>Logout</a>";

}
```